# SQL ORDER BY - Keep column with same value grouped

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a lot of difficulties to express in words what I want (this title is the best I could come with), it's easier with a schema, but I'll first try to explain myself.

I want to order by a query using this rule:

1. Group the query by their "Group" column.
2. Place the "Primary" of each group on top of their group.
3. If a rows have the same "Name" as the primary, place it just after their primary.
4. Place the rest of the rows by their names

Points 1, 2 and 4 are trivial. A simple ORDER BY to the trick. But I have never seen a query with point 3.

I've read a bit about [RANK()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql) and [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) functions, tried them out, but I haven't manage to create the output I want. I'm starting to question if it's even possible to do so.

Anyway, here's a chunk of SQL to test it out. Any help is appreciated. If you can find better terms to describe this, feel free to correct.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
    COL_GROUP INT,
    COL_PRIMARY BIT,
    COL_NAME VARCHAR(3)
)

INSERT INTO 
    #TEMP 
VALUES
    (1,1,'AAA'),
    (2,0,'BBB'),
    (2,1,'BBB'),
    (1,0,'BBB'),
    (1,0,'AAA'),
    (2,0,'AAA')

SELECT
     *
FROM 
    #TEMP
ORDER BY 
    COL_GROUP, 
    COL_PRIMARY DESC, 
    COL_NAME

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

This gives this output:

```
COL_GROUP   COL_PRIMARY   COL_NAME
=========   ===========   ========
1           1             AAA  
1           0             AAA
1           0             BBB
2           1             BBB
2           0             AAA
2           0             BBB
```

What I want is this output:

```
COL_GROUP   COL_PRIMARY   COL_NAME
=========   ===========   ========
1           1             AAA  
1           0             AAA
1           0             BBB
2           1             BBB
2           0             BBB       -- The ones with the same name as the primary first
2           0             AAA
```

Comment: You could do a self-join and test if the name is equal to the primary, and if so assign the value of e.g. 1 else 0, then use that column in your `ORDER BY`, before the `COL_NAME` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution as per comment

> You could do a self-join and test if the name is equal to the primary, and if so assign the value of e.g. 1 else 0, then use that column in your order by, before the name column.

```
SELECT
     T1.*
FROM 
    #TEMP T1 JOIN #TEMP T2 
    ON T1.COL_GROUP=T2.COL_GROUP AND T2.COL_PRIMARY=1
ORDER BY 
    T1.COL_GROUP, 
    T1.COL_PRIMARY DESC,
    CASE WHEN T1.COL_NAME=T2.COL_NAME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
    T1.COL_NAME
```

<kbd>**[See demo here](http://rextester.com/BRBJB17117)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Use `max` window function to get the col_name for col_primary = 1 and use it in a `case` expression in `order by` for the desired order.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
     t.*,max(case when col_primary=1 then col_name end) over(partition by col_group) as prim_col_name
FROM 
    #TEMP t
) t
ORDER BY 
    COL_GROUP, 
    COL_PRIMARY DESC, 
    case when COL_NAME = prim_col_name then 1 else 2 end,
    COL_NAME
```

This assumes there can only be one row per col_primary=1 per col_group.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.
It does want I want, but since @DhruvJoshi answers (and Steffen Sylvest Nielsen's comment) seems more clean, I will go if their answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM #TEMP o
ORDER BY COL_GROUP, COL_PRIMARY DESC, CASE WHEN COL_NAME = (SELECT COL_Name FROM #Temp i WHERE i.COL_PRimary = 1 AND i.Col_Group = o.Col_Group) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, COL_NAME;
```

Basically I am doing a nested select of an inner reference to the same dataset as the outer but limiting scope to say: "I want the name where it matches the leader of the group and then make it 0 else 1".  This will work fine for small sets but as another user has shown you may want to break it into a CTE and call it later if it is a large dataset.  If you are only doing a few thousand rows or less, this should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The order by should be applied to at max a hundred rows.
I think I will go with @DhruvJoshi answer (and Steffen Sylvest Nielsen's comment), since it seems more clean.

Comment: No problem, nested selects can get messy and I understand.   His will probably work better on a larger dataset as I mentioned too.

Answer (score 0):

Using a **left join** on the table itself will make sure you will not loose any records in case there is no primary item in the group (Maby it is'nt an issue).

This will also simplify the "**order by**" simply by adding the linked column T2.COL_NAME(wich will not be null if COL_NAME is the same as primary).

```
SELECT
         T1.*
FROM 
        #TEMP T1
        left join #TEMP T2 on T2.COL_GROUP = T1.COL_GROUP and T2.COL_NAME  = T1.COL_NAME and T2.COL_PRIMARY = 1
ORDER BY 
        T1.COL_GROUP, 
        T1.COL_PRIMARY DESC, 
        T2.COL_NAME DESC,
        T1.COL_NAME
```